# How to get more than 6 months of data from GDELT using Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, gdelt

I could not get more than 6 months of data from GDELT [gkg table](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg).

For example, this query returns only results from 19 Feb 2015:

```
SELECT Date, SourceCommonName, DocumentIdentifier FROM [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg] 
where (date < 20150220000000 and locations like "%Israel%" and    
SourceCommonName = "cnn.com")
```

The same query for date < 20150219000000 returns no results

How can I get older results/ why aren't older results returned?

Comment: You realize that no one can see your table, even if you linked into it? Without seeing it the best theory I can come up with is that all the results from your query are older than that? We'd need to see your schema, a little idea into the data you have, which rows SHOULD be returned, etc

Comment: @Patrice this is a public table, so anyone can query if. Check out the GDELT project here: http://blog.gdeltproject.org/google-bigquery-gkg-2-0-sample-queries/

Comment: @jordantigani thanks for that! I was not aware of it, and the link polina link didn't work and gave me a bad link. maybe I need to check your link then :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table you refer to has only been updated since January 2015 as you note. This is the announcement for GDELT v2: http://blog.gdeltproject.org/gdelt-2-0-our-global-world-in-realtime/

V1 has data for the last 30 years, and available at https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/gdelt-bq:full.events, but not as rich as the gkg in v2.

Maybe contact Kalev at the GDELT project to have GKG filled back for previous years?